# Expo Push Notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am using Expo Push Notification. I proceeded according to the instructions on the Expo site [expo-push-notifications](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/), but I realized that in order to receive the Expo Push Token, we must have an Expo account, and before running the project, we must log in to our account using the Expo Login command and then run the project.My question is, when the build project is taken out and put into production mode, do these services still work properly or do we have to apply certain settings and the Expo site tips are only for the development phase? I am a beginner in developing React Native programs and I have no special experience in this field. Please share your experiences with Expo Push Notification with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your app on Expo servers for example by `expo build:ios` command, it is handled by Expo services, but if you decided to build your app through, for example, Github Actions, you have to deliver APN keys to Expo by your own through `expo credentials:manager`. On your Expo account are stored credential files to use by Expo PUSH Broadcaster, so this connection between the app and your account is required.

Here you can find more details about signing your applications:
https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-signing/#push-notification-keys